# `+' nil can't be coerced into FixNum (TypeError) won't go away

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop, null, fixnum

I'm using HTTParty to connect to stockfighter.io 's API and getting a quote of a stock, which I then extract a price per share from and append it to the end of the `$averageArr` array.

I'm trying to average the last five values of a constantly updating array, `$averageArr`, and so I thought I would make a variable `sum` set it to zero, add those last five values to it and then divide it by 5 to get a dynamic and changing average.

Here's my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

apikey = 'API_KEY_FOR_LOGIN_HERE'
venue = "VENUEX"
stock = "FOOBAR"

base_url = "https://api.stockfighter.io/ob/api"

account = "MY_ACCOUNT_HERE"

$averageArr = []

$counter = 0

$currAve = 0


def getQuote(stock, venue, account)

    response = HTTParty.get("https://api.stockfighter.io/ob/api/venues/#{venue}/stocks/#{stock}/quote")

    orderbook = response.parsed_response

    puts orderbook["ok"]

    return orderbook["last"]
    puts orderbook["lastTrade"]

end


def getAverage(stock, venue, account)

    $averageArr.push(getQuote(stock, venue, account))
    $counter += 1

    if $counter > 5

        sum = 0

        #line 43
        for i in 1..5 do
            # this one is line 45
            sum += $averageArr[$averageArr.count - i]

        end


        return sum/5
        $currAve = sum/5

    else

        return 'WAITING FOR QUOTE. CURRENT:'

    end
end


# line 62
for i in 1..10 do

    # line 64
    getAverage(stock, venue, account)

    if $counter > 5

        if getQuote(stock, venue, account) < $currAve - 25 and numShares < 999

            order = {

                    "account" => account,
                    "venue" => venue,
                    "symbol" => stock,
                    "price" => 1,  #$250.00 -- probably ludicrously high
                    "qty" => 1,
                    "direction" => "buy",
                    "orderType" => "market"  # See the order docs for what a limit order is

                  }

            response = HTTParty.post("#{base_url}/venues/#{venue}/stocks/#{stock}/orders",
                                   :body => JSON.dump(order),
                                   :headers => {"X-Starfighter-Authorization" => apikey}
                                   )

        elsif getQuote(stock, venue, account) > $currAve + 25 and numShares > 0

            order = {

                    "account" => account,
                    "venue" => venue,
                    "symbol" => stock,
                    "price" => 1,  #$250.00 -- probably ludicrously high
                    "qty" => 1,
                    "direction" => "sell",
                    "orderType" => "market"  # See the order docs for what a limit order is

                  }

            response = HTTParty.post("#{base_url}/venues/#{venue}/stocks/#{stock}/orders",
                                   :body => JSON.dump(order),
                                   :headers => {"X-Starfighter-Authorization" => apikey}
                                   )

        end
    end
end
```

I've been having difficulty with line 45 (commented), in which I get errors about `FixNum` and `nil`:

```
/Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:45:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
from /Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:45:in `block in getAverage'
from /Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:43:in `each'
from /Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:43:in `getAverage'
from /Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:64:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:62:in `each'
from /Users/kaichristensen/Dropbox/Kai/Stockfighter/level_three_selling.rb:62:in `<main>'
```

I might be trying to access and index out of scope on the array, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code has a lot of mistakes. To get rid of this error you can add ``.to_i`` to the end of this line like this: ``$averageArr.last.to_i``. Bet this won't help you much.

Comment: Thankyou! I will try this!

Comment: @lurker Take a look at the previous line. ``puts`` will never be called.

Comment: A shorter way to get the average: `$averageArr.map(&:to_i).sum  / $averageArr.length`

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko oops sorry, yes you're right, my eye was just focusing on that last statement.

Comment: Are you sure `orderbook["last"]` is never `nil`? You might want to do some debugging to find out. Your `getAverage` actually returns a string when `$counter` is less than or equal to 5, which also looks wrong. And you have a `return ...` before `$currAve = sum/5` so that statement will never be reached. Just to name a few issues...

Comment: It throws the error because Ruby was never designed as a web-scripting language.  Obviously, you don't want to get a page-crash on nil - it should evaluate to zero in this context, automatically.  The "to_i" and "to_f" methods, appended on each variable where those are expected, can trick Ruby into not crashing idiotically on those, but won't help when you need a decimal ("to_d" on a nil "crashes" swell!) - so must check every variable in every calculation/equation to "check if its nil" on currency variables = countless wasted time +confusing code to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is fine. The problem is that your methods are not validating data.

`a += b` expands to `a = a + b`, which will throw the error you're facing when `b` is `nil`.

You need to make sure that `getQuote` always returns a number, or cast whatever you want to average into a number before performing mathematical operations.

For the former, you can change `return orderbook["last"]` to `return orderbook["last"].to_f`

For the latter,  `sum += $averageArr[$averageArr.count - i].to_f`